# Changing characters on bluetooth keyboard layout

Tags: external-keyboard, text-layout

I have Lenovo m10 with external bluetooth keyboard on which I use my language layout (Croatian). The problem is that it types some characters wrong. For example, it types some characters in capital when it shouldn't.

It looks like this when I type: **priČekaj**, or when I press Caps lock: **PRIčEKAJ**.
How can I fix this?

Sorry for bad English and thank you!!!